# How to call DROP USER from pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

How to call `DROP USER` from Pl/PgSql (see example) ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myfunc()
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
DECLARE
  super_users TEXT[];
  ldap_users TEXT[];
  u TEXT;
BEGIN
  super_users := ARRAY(SELECT usename::TEXT FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usesuper);
  ldap_users := ARRAY(SELECT uid::TEXT FROM ldap_users);

  FOREACH u IN ARRAY ldap_users LOOP
    IF (u <> 'postgres' AND u <> ALL(super_users)) THEN
      DROP USER IF EXISTS u;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

It leads to error that "role u does not exist"...

IMHO PL/PGSQL does not treat `u` as a variable, but as a name. And `DROP USER...` is not SQL but some extension. How to do it? Maybe some system function? Or special syntax to substitute `u`?

**EDIT:
My solution (just found):**

```
DECLARE
  stm TEXT;
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  stm := 'DROP USER IF EXISTS "' || u '"';
  EXECUTE stm;
...
```

It seems to work. Maybe there is other solutions? More canonical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for this:

```
execute format('DROP USER IF EXISTS %I', u);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DROP OWNED BY user;
DROP ROLE user;
DROP USER user;
```

**It works for me.**

*P.d: After checking SOF, you can try:*

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public FROM user;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public FROM user;
DROP USER user;
```

*Cheers mate.*